# Other radiogroup not displaying on frame

Tags: java, swing

ButtonGroup not working when adding directly to the frame that's why I added the radiobuttons directly on the frame. However I only see radiobutton. Am I doing the wrong method here? Can someone help me on this.

```
  protected ButtonGroup radioGroup = new ButtonGroup();  
protected JRadioButton small = new JRadioButton("small");
protected JRadioButton medium = new JRadioButton("medium");
protected JRadioButton large = new JRadioButton("large");

public PlayingWithShapes()
{

    shapes.add(circle);
    shapes.add(square); 
    shapes.add(rectangle);
    shapes.add(triangle);

    colors.add(red);
    colors.add(blue);
    colors.add(magenta);

    radioGroup.add(small);
    radioGroup.add(medium);
    radioGroup.add(large);

    menuBar.add(shapes);
    menuBar.add(colors);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Playing With Shapes");
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    frame.add(this);
    frame.add(small);
    frame.add(medium);
    frame.add(large);
    frame.setSize(600,400);
```

Comment: `JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout` by default, so you kind of screwed yourself there

Comment: @MadProgrammer Any example then?Thank you

Comment: @JayGorio `Any example then?` - you have already been given an example. Did you read the answer or did I waste my time typing the answser?

Comment: @JayGorio Use a more applicable layout manager, have a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
frame.add(small);
frame.add(medium);
frame.add(large);
```

The default layout for a frame is a BorderLayout. You can only add a single component to the CENTER of the BorderLayout.

You need to either:

1. Change the layout manager of the frame
2. Add your buttons to a panel and then add the panel to the frame.

Check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for a working example with radio buttons.

The tutorial also has a section on `Layout Managers` that you should read up on.

Comment: Thanks but It only shows the radiobuttons but my other shapes not displaying

Comment: @JayGorio, . We are not here to write the code for you. You have been given a link to the Swing tutorial that has example of using layout managers. There is no way you could have read the tutorial and played with the example in 5 minutes. Start with the working code and modify it instead of using your code. Also we have no idea what your "shapes" and "colors" variables are. There is also a tutorial on "How to Use Menus" that you can look at. You were given a link to the tutorial for a reason. Use it as a resource.

Comment: Okay I got it now it's working. Thanks for all effort.

Comment: @JayGorio, glad the comments and tutorials helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer so people know the problem has been solved.